Displaying a Native Swift Alert When a JavaScript Method is Called in WebKit for iOS
I am developing an iOS app using WebKit. In my app, there is a website that includes a JavaScript method called showEnvConnectOptions(). I would like a native Swift alert to appear in the app whenever this JavaScript method is called.
I have tried WK Script message Handler
Below is the code
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let contentController = WKUserContentController()
        contentController.add(self, name: "showEnvConnectOptions")

        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController

        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame, configuration: config)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)

        if let url = URL(string: "https://your-webpage-url.com") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }

        let js = """
        window.showEnvConnectOptions = function() {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.showEnvConnectOptions.postMessage(null);
        }
        """
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(js, completionHandler: nil)
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "showEnvConnectOptions" {
            showEnvConnectOptions()
        }
    }

    func showEnvConnectOptions() {
        print("showEnvConnectOptions called")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Environment Connect Options", message: "Showing environment connect options.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

I am getting this as the warning even i have added the entitlements
ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=88,688, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
